# Why are transitive dependencies not detected?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have Scala library based on SBT, which I publish to Maven repository:

```
organization := "com.mycompany"
name := "mylib"
version := "0.0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.6", "2.11.7")
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-unchecked", "-deprecation")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.2.0",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.3.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.13",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.13"
)

isSnapshot := true
publishMavenStyle := true
publishTo := {
  Some(s3resolver.value("My Repo", s3("mybucket")).withMavenPatterns)
}
```

I include this library into another project:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.mycompany" %% "mylib" % "0.0.1"
)
```

Running `sbt sbt-dependency dependencyTree` only shows:

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] default:another-project_2.10:1.2 [S]
[info]   +-com.mycompany:mylib_2.10:0.0.1
[info]
```

I'm not able to see all the 3rd party dependencies: `org.scalaj`, `org.json4s`, etc.

EDIT: Moreover, when building an assembly, these dependencies are missing from the uberjar as well.

The .pom file deployed to the Maven repository do contain all the mentioned dependencies, while `~/.ivy2/cache/com.mycompany/mylib_2.10/ivy-0.0.1.xml` does not.

Running `sbt about` in mylib/ shows:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/michael/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/project
[info] Set current project to mylib (in build file:/home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.9
[info] The current project is {file:/home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/}mylib 0.0.1
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.6
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, ohnosequences.sbt.SbtS3Resolver
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.5
```

Running `sbt about` in otherproject/ shows:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/michael/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/michael/Dev/projects/otherproject/project
[info] Set current project to otherproject (in build file:/home/michael/Dev/projects/otherproject/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/michael/Dev/projects/otherproject/}otherproject...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] This is sbt 0.13.9
[info] The current project is {file:/home/michael/Dev/projects/otherproject/}otherproject 1.2
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.6
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, ohnosequences.sbt.SbtS3Resolver, net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.DependencyGraphPlugin, sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.5
```

Here's the output from publishing to a local directory:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/michael/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/project
[info] Set current project to mylib (in build file:/home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/}mylib...
[info] Packaging /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/target/scala-2.10/mylib_2.10-0.0.1-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/target/scala-2.10/mylib_2.10-0.0.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] :: delivering :: com.mycompany#mylib_2.10;0.0.1 :: 0.0.1 :: integration :: Sat Jan 09 16:10:20 IST 2016
[info]  delivering ivy file to /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/target/scala-2.10/ivy-0.0.1.xml
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/target/scala-2.10/api...
[info] Packaging /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/target/scala-2.10/mylib_2.10-0.0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
model contains 9 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/target/scala-2.10/mylib_2.10-0.0.1-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published mylib_2.10 to /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/releases/com/mycompany/mylib_2.10/0.0.1/mylib_2.10-0.0.1.pom
[info]  published mylib_2.10 to /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/releases/com/mycompany/mylib_2.10/0.0.1/mylib_2.10-0.0.1.jar
[info]  published mylib_2.10 to /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/releases/com/mycompany/mylib_2.10/0.0.1/mylib_2.10-0.0.1-sources.jar
[info]  published mylib_2.10 to /home/michael/Dev/projects/mylib/releases/com/mycompany/mylib_2.10/0.0.1/mylib_2.10-0.0.1-javadoc.jar
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jan 9, 2016 4:10:23 PM
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is `isSnapshot := true` since `"0.0.1"` is stable, i.e. non-snapshot version?

Comment: This is just for testing purposes, in order to enable publisher overwrite artifacts. I tried disabling it though, with no luck

Comment: Can you do `sbt about` in both projects? What version of sbt-dependency-graph do you use? Can you use `publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", new File("releases")))` instead (not s3)? Please include the outputs to the question. (spoiler: it works for me)

Answer (score 0):

Your `build.sbt` file contains the line

```
publishMavenStyle := true
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html#Modifying+the+generated+POM)

> a POM is generated by the makePom action and published to the
>   repository instead of an Ivy file

I can suppose that `ivy.xml` is just not generated and the one that you see is a residue from a previous run, when `publishMavenStyle` was not (yet) set.

Since your artifact is published into the Maven repository, have you tried to remove the one from `~/.ivy2/cache/com.mycompany/mylib_2.10` and check the result of dependency tree listing?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing `~/.ivy/cache/com.mycompany` as well as `~/.m2/repository/com/mycompany` (just in case), and re-checking the dependency tree. `ivy-0.0.1.xml` file is still re-created without the dependencies inside.